# "Massaging" inequalities to prove them (esp. in contest math like the IMO/Putnam)?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

What's the contest inequality solving technique where you do something like representing each side as the function of some sequence and replacing the max/min terms of the sequence with their average, and then demonstrating something about the new form, and repeating that? It went something like that, at least, but I don't remember very well (so the description above might be completely botched, so hopefully it conveys the idea correctly), and want to know the English name. My professor called it "massaging" the inequality, but that was probably a non-canonical ad-hoc translation; she said that the name in Russian was something more like "beating the inequality with a big stick".

My professor also mentioned that her friend in high school (in Russia, I think) used it to solve almost every inequality problem (in contests & on the IMO) and that, while it was often very algebraically nasty, it did work for >90% of all inequality problems.

It would be useful if I could find some sort of small primer on the technique.

Comment: Maybe you could give some examples.

Comment: Are you thinking of "smoothing"?